# Cloud Storage for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

Hi I am creating an Android application. I had intended to use SQLite as the database as it will only be a relatively small db and host that in the cloud but i am a little confused on how to do it.There seems to be alot of options Azure, Aws etc 
Two Questions:

1. Do i save to localdb then sync to the cloud (this way if user has no
   connection) or do i sync straight to the cloud ?
2. Is the Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) what i should use?

Thanks in Advance for your help

Comment: You might want to consider using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). It takes care of all the sync for you

Comment: Firebase is a good recommendation. S3 is not at all what you are looking for, since it is used to store objects (files), not databases.

Comment: I will be saving images as well so im not sure if the Firebase Realtime Database will work , i know they have a storage for images. Do i just have to reference both the  Realtime Database and the storage ??